# options.remove(); doesn't work, weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, php, select

I've got a paypal select, where I have different options. I want to choose just one option and erase the rest of them. To do so I've got this piece of code:

```
var selectobject=document.getElementById("os0"); //this is the select
        for (var i=0; i<selectobject.length; i++){
        if (selectobject.options[i].value != <?php echo $people; ?> ){
            selectobject.remove(i);
            alert(i);
        }
    }
```

And here is the select from paypal,

```
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="people">people</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0" id="os0">
    <option id="1" value="1">1 €123,97 EUR</option>
    <option id="2" value="2">2 €249,94 EUR</option>
    <option id="3" value="3">3 €371,91 EUR</option>
    <option id="4" value="4">4 €495,88 EUR</option>
    <option id="5" value="5">5 €619,85 EUR</option>
    <option id="6" value="6">6 €743,82 EUR</option>
    <option id="7" value="7">7 €867,79 EUR</option>
    <option id="8" value="8">8 €991,76 EUR</option>
    <option id="9" value="9">9 €1.115,73 EUR</option>
    <option id="10" value="10">10 €1.239,70 EUR</option>
</select>
```

So what happens is super weird, it erases just tha paar numbers, and just counts until 5 or 6, the result if I send for example 1 persons is:

- 1 €123,97 EUR
- 3 €371,91 EUR
- 5 €619,85 EUR
- 7 €867,79 EUR
- 9 €1.115,73 EUR

and if I choose 2 people:

- 2 €249,94 EUR
- 4 €495,88 EUR
- 6 €743,82 EUR
- 8 €991,76 EUR
- 10 €1.239,70 EUR

I've got also an alert to tell me where is "i" and it just goes up to 5 or 4, don't understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you remove the option at `i`, you're shuffling all the other options down; so now, the next option is at `i`. But then because you're using a `for` loop, you're incrementing `i` — and you never looked at the option after the option you removed.

Instead, use a `while` loop and only increment `i` if you don't remove the option.

```
var selectobject = document.getElementById("os0"); //this is the select
var i = 0;
while (i < selectobject.length) {
    if (selectobject.options[i].value != <?php echo $people; ?> ){
        selectobject.remove(i);
        alert(i);
    } else {
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Live Example using `3` (and without the `alert`):

```js
var people = 3;
var selectobject = document.getElementById("os0"); //this is the select
var i = 0;
while (i < selectobject.length) {
    if (selectobject.options[i].value != people){
        selectobject.remove(i);
    } else {
        ++i;
    }
}
```

```html
<select name="os0" id="os0">
    <option id="1" value="1">1 €123,97 EUR</option>
    <option id="2" value="2">2 €249,94 EUR</option>
    <option id="3" value="3">3 €371,91 EUR</option>
    <option id="4" value="4">4 €495,88 EUR</option>
    <option id="5" value="5">5 €619,85 EUR</option>
    <option id="6" value="6">6 €743,82 EUR</option>
    <option id="7" value="7">7 €867,79 EUR</option>
    <option id="8" value="8">8 €991,76 EUR</option>
    <option id="9" value="9">9 €1.115,73 EUR</option>
    <option id="10" value="10">10 €1.239,70 EUR</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hey! That works, Thank you!! I didn't think about that index stuff!

Answer (score 0):

When you remove items while iterating over them, the element currently processed in `i` will be offset each time an item is removed.

If you remove them in reverse you shouldn't have the issue. See example below if element with value `9` was desired.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  var selectobject = document.getElementById("os0"); //this is the select
  for (var i = selectobject.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (selectobject.options[i].value != 9) {
      selectobject.remove(i);
    }
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="people">people</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><select name="os0" id="os0">
    <option id="1" value="1">1 €123,97 EUR</option>
    <option id="2" value="2">2 €249,94 EUR</option>
    <option id="3" value="3">3 €371,91 EUR</option>
    <option id="4" value="4">4 €495,88 EUR</option>
    <option id="5" value="5">5 €619,85 EUR</option>
    <option id="6" value="6">6 €743,82 EUR</option>
    <option id="7" value="7">7 €867,79 EUR</option>
    <option id="8" value="8">8 €991,76 EUR</option>
    <option id="9" value="9">9 €1.115,73 EUR</option>
    <option id="10" value="10">10 €1.239,70 EUR</option>
</select>
```